# How to show and hide Google Material FloatingAction Button

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

I want to show/hide Google Material Floating Action button programmatically. I'm using Google Material library

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

And use the following code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.hide() // This is the method to hide the button as the Documentation But This does not hide the button

    fab.setVisibility(View.GONE) // Neither this work, 
}
```

Is there any other specific method to hide it?

Comment: Shouldn't be there `R.id.fab`?

Comment: Yes @SkypeDogg, It was writing a mistake on this. But the issue is still there

Comment: I am using `FloatingActionButton` inside my project, but I don't import `'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'` it is inside `'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'`. I'm not sure if it might be a problem, but it's only difference I can see there, because I hide and show it and it works as it should